# How can I run ipconfig on FreeDos?

Tags: ipconfig, freedos

I have been trying to run a ipconfig.exe file on FreeDos. Do I Need to convert it to ipconfig.com or is there an other way to solve this? 
I've already tried to make a .bat file, which i hoped could Bypass the .exe restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there is no network preinstalled with FreeDOS.

But the installer makes it pretty simple to set it up.

1. Install FreeDOS according to http://www.freedos.org/install/
2. Afterwards, leave the CD in the tray, reboot and choose "Boot from system harddisk".

[image: reboot.png]

3. After the reboot run the package manager FDIMPLES:

[image: fdimples.png]

(The install CD has to be present to see all the packages available.)

1. In the left window choose Networking, in the right the programs you wish to install.
2. FDNET is mandatory for networking in virtual machines. I would also recommend at least mTCP and wget. Confirm with OK.
3. Reboot.

After reboot, you can see IP information like below.

[image: boot-process]

The boot messages above show that the C:\FDOS\BIN\FDNET.BAT network batch file was able to identify my system correctly as running in VirtualBox. It loaded the correct packet driver PCNTPK.COM. DHCP.EXE from mTCP also found the network and was configured automatically.

So far FDNET.BAT is able to identify the following virtual machines: QEMU, VirtualBox, VMWARE.

> It is quotated from http://wiki.freedos.org